# ¿Cómo obtener correctamente una variable de una base de datos con fetch?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que funcione? no lee las variables: `$acc2pay['value']`, `$acc2pay['user_id']` y `$acc2pay['ptsu_id']`.

```
<?php
try
{

$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$db", $usuario, $contrasena);

}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo "There was an unexpected error. Please try again, or contact us with concerns";
}

$mid = '2597';
$acc2pay = $conexion->prepare("SELECT user_id, value, ptsu_id FROM ptsu_requests WHERE id='" . $mid . "'");
$acc2pay = $acc2pay->fetch();
$upd = $conexion->query("UPDATE ptsu_requests SET status='Completed' WHERE id=" . $mid);
$upd = $conexion->query("UPDATE members SET money=money+" . $acc2pay['value'] . " WHERE id=" . $acc2pay['user_id']);
$upd = $conexion->query("UPDATE ptsu_offers SET approved=approved+1, pending=pending-1 WHERE id=" . $acc2pay['ptsu_id']);
```

Comment: No puedes hacer un `fetch` de un `prepare` sin haber ejecutado la consulta con un `execute`. Además, no deberías concatenar cadenas de caracteres a consultas SQL, para eso están precisamente las consultas preparadas (usando `prepare`).

Answer (score 3):

El motivo por el que no obtienes la información que deseas en `$acc2pay['value']`, `$acc2pay['user_id']` y `$acc2pay['ptsu_id']` es debido a que estás tratando de hacer un [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetch) de una consulta preparada que no ha sido ejecutada aún con [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.execute), sólo preparada con [`PDOStatement::prepare()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.prepare).

La solución más fácil a tu problema sería cambiar el [`PDO::prepare()`](http://php.net/pdo.prepare) por un [`PDO::query()`](http://php.net/pdo.query) como el resto de consultas.

No hay que olvidar usar [`PDO::quote()`](http://php.net/pdo.quote) para no sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) al concatenar cadenas de texto a consultas SQL:

```
<?php
/* Realizamos la consulta (usando PDO::quote) */
$acc2pay = $conexion->query("
  SELECT
    user_id, value, ptsu_id
  FROM ptsu_requests
  WHERE id = " . $conexion->quote($mid) . "
");
/* Comprobamos si hubo un error en la consulta */
if ($acc2pay === false) {
    /* Obtenemos los detalles del error */
    $errores = $conexion->errorInfo();
    /* Mostramos el texto del error */
    die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars($errores[2]));
}
/* Obtenemos el primer y único registro (si existe) */
$acc2pay = $acc2pay->fetch();
/* Comprobamos si existe o no algún registro con dicho "id" */
if ($acc2pay === false) {
    die('No existe ningún registro con ese "id"');
}
```

He controlado si `$acc2pay` vale `false`. En ese caso significaría que no había ningún registro con ese identificador.

También he comprobado si `query()` devuelve `false`. En ese otro caso significaría que hubo un error o problema con la consulta.

---

Además, como bien sugiere [@A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano), deberías usar consultas preparadas en vez de abusar del uso de [`PDO::quote()`](http://php.net/pdo.quote).

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo quedaría tu código usando consultas preparadas y comprobado la salida de cada consulta:

```
<?php
try {
    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$db", $usuario, $contrasena);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "There was an unexpected error. Please try again, or contact us with concerns";
}

$mid = '2597';
/* Realizamos la consulta (usando consultas preparadas) */
$acc2pay = $conexion->prepare("
  SELECT
    user_id, value, ptsu_id
  FROM ptsu_requests
  WHERE id = :id
");
/* Ejecutamos la consulta asignando el valor adecuado a :id y
    comprobamos si hubo un error durante la ejecución de la consulta */
if (
    $acc2pay->execute([
      ':id' => $mid,
    ]) === false
) {
    /* Obtenemos los detalles del error */
    $errores = $acc2pay->errorInfo();
    /* Mostramos el texto del error */
    die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars($errores[2]));
}
/* Obtenemos el primer y único registro (si existe) */
$acc2pay = $acc2pay->fetch();
if ($acc2pay === false) {
    die('No existe ningún registro con ese "id"');
}
$upd = $conexion->prepare("
  UPDATE ptsu_requests
  SET status = 'Completed'
  WHERE id = :id
");
if (
    $upd->execute([
      ':id' => $mid,
    ]) === false
) {
    /* Obtenemos los detalles del error */
    $errores = $acc2pay->errorInfo();
    /* Mostramos el texto del error */
    die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars($errores[2]));
}
$upd = $conexion->query("
  UPDATE members
  SET money = money + :value
  WHERE id = :id
");
if (
    /* OJO: Esta consulta requiere definir :value e :id */
    $upd->execute([
      ':value' => $acc2pay['value'],
      ':id' => $mid,
    ]) === false
) {
    /* Obtenemos los detalles del error */
    $errores = $acc2pay->errorInfo();
    /* Mostramos el texto del error */
    die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars($errores[2]));
}
$upd = $conexion->query("
  UPDATE ptsu_offers
  SET approved = approved + 1, pending = pending - 1
  WHERE id = :id
");
if (
    $upd->execute([
      ':id' => $mid,
    ]) === false
) {
    /* Obtenemos los detalles del error */
    $errores = $acc2pay->errorInfo();
    /* Mostramos el texto del error */
    die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars($errores[2]));
}
```

Se podrían evitar tantos bloques `if/then/else` con un único bloque `try/catch` activando la generación de excepciones en caso de error con [`$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`](http://php.net/pdo.setattribute).

Por último, quizá deberías realizar las actualizaciones dentro de una transacción para que todo se realice o no en bloque. Consulta la documentación de [`PDO::beginTransaction()`](http://php.net/pdo.begintransaction) y [`PDO::commit()`](http://php.net/pdo.commit) para más información.

Comment: Oscar ¿no te percataste de que **está usando PDO**?, no tiene nada que ver con `mysqli`, los métodos para PDO son diferentes. Además, ¿por qué no aprovechas para implementar consultas preparadas, quitando tanta *basura* del código y sobre todo aportando seguridad? De hecho, con PDO no hay que detenerse en tantas explicaciones como en mysqli para aplicar las consultas preparadas.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Todo un despiste por mi parte xD Ahora mismo hago los cambios :D Aún así el concepto es el mismo ;)

Comment: Cambios realizados. Gracias de nuevo @A.Cedano :) Acabo de comprobar que es posible que mi confusión empezara por las etiquetas de la pregunta que incluían `mysqli`. Ya la he cambiado por `pdo`.

Comment: Oscar, cuando decía *quitar tanta basura del código dándole seguridad* me refería a cambiar esto: `$acc2pay = $conexion->query("
  SELECT
    user_id, value, ptsu_id
  FROM ptsu_requests
  WHERE id = " . $conexion->quote($mid) . "
");` por esto: `$acc2pay = $conexion->prepare("
  SELECT
    user_id, value, ptsu_id
  FROM ptsu_requests
  WHERE id = ?
"); $acc2pay->execute(array($mid));` Es **tan fácil en PDO pasar de una consulta peligrosa y sucia a una  limpia y segura** que me parece una pena no mostrar ese camino.

Comment: Perdona de nuevo. No leí tu comentario entero (respondí en un hueco del trabajo y ahora trato de corregir la respuesta a prisas y corriendo). Es cierto que es mucho más fácil convertir a consultas preparadas en PDO, pero quería centrarme en el motivo por el que no le funcionaba la consulta (usar `fetch()` antes de un `execute()`). Propondré los cambios al final, para seguir resaltando ese detalle, pero no podré editar la respuesta hasta dentro de una hora (más o menos). Gracias de nuevo por tus comentarios :)

Comment: No hay problema Oscar, tus respuestas siempre brillan por su calidad y claridad. De hecho me sorprendió que se te escapase ese detalle. Hice el comentario con la intención de que la respuesta sea mejorada y puede servir mejor al OP y a futuros usuarios. Saludos y gracias por tus respuestas siempre bien elaboradas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84187/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-oscargarcia).